# Random intercepts model with no constant, no fixed effects

Tags: r, python, random-effects-model

My understanding is that the following model is a random intercepts model with no constant. Therefore, lmer provides a random coefficient for each group (since the constant is omitted).

```
fit=lmer(y~-1+(1|groupid),data=df)
```

Is this understanding correct? If there is no fixed effects term and no constant, what actually is happening? I'm not sure what the underlying model is. Is it:

$y_i = \beta * GroupID_i + u_i$

Bonus: I'm trying to figure out the equivalent model in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model you're fitting is: $$\left \{ \begin{array}{l} y_{ij} = b_i + \varepsilon_{ij},\\ &\\ b_i \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma_b^2), \quad \varepsilon_{ij} \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma^2),\end{array} \right.$$ where $y_{ij}$ denotes the $j$-th measurement of the $i$-th sample unit / group.

You only get estimates for $\sigma_b^2$ the variance of the random intercepts, and $\sigma^2$ the variance of the error terms.

In a second step, and from the posterior distribution of the random effects $[b_i \mid y_i]$, where $y_i$ denotes the vector of the measurements of the $i$-th group, you can get (posterior) estimates of the intercept per group. Note, that even though a-priori the random effects have mean zero, a-posteriori the estimated random intercepts may have a mean different from zero.

Comment: That explains the underlying model, thanks. If anyone knows equivalent Python code, please let me know.